# How does php's mail() function handles sending email?

Tags: php, email

I was just wondering how does PHP's `mail()` function handles email sending. Because we do not provide any SMTP server, e-mail username and password and it still it sends email.

How is that possible?

Comment: `main()` or `mail()` ?

Comment: For the mail functions to be available, PHP requires an installed and working email system. The program to be used is defined by the configuration settings in the php.ini file.

Comment: @Sadikhasan I'm sorry, I edited the question it's mail()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The php mail() function sends the mail from the server itself.
Any server who's node is connected to the internet is able to send mails.

It is strongly recommended that you go via. a SMTP server, since spam filters do not like mails sent from most unrecognised IP addresses.

Comment: What do you mean from the server itself? Let's say I have a WAMPServer installed on Windows 8 PC, where is the server? I didn't install any SMTP server and anything like that.

Comment: On Linux, PHP uses an application called sendmail. Of course there is no similar applicaion on Windows. As php.ini file says, to be able to work with mail function, you need to setup mail server coordinates. If You don't have mail server, it is not possible to send emails from PHP. Of course You could use some external server like gmail.